# Is the public address for Tesla's wallet known?

Tags: wallet, address, wallet-security, news-coverage

I understand if this isn't likely the place.

It has been all over the news that [Tesla has bought 1.5 billion in bitcoin](https://www.cnbc.com/2021/02/08/tesla-buys-1point5-billion-in-bitcoin.html). I'm curious if tesla's public wallet address(es) are known?

If they are not known, what is the most likely culprit? shouldn't it be public information?

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not known, and information like that generally won't be publicly released. Bitcoin addresses aren't generally publicly associated with the real-life identities of their owners.

I would expect a company like Tesla to have the bulk of their cryptocurrency assets stored in institutional custody regardless, for liability and regulatory reasons.